# Are there any browser based upload progress bars that can upload multiple folders?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, file-upload, progress-bar

I'm aware of upload progress bars that can upload multiple files (ex. http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm or http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) but I haven't been able to find any that can select multiple folders.

I'm working on a music analysis site, so it would be great if people could upload multiple albums at once (like in iTunes.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a java app to do that, such as the one [Aurigma](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/OnlineDemo.aspx) uses. I don't know any off the top of my head though.

EDIT: Here's one: [Java Multiple File Upload](http://www.jfileupload.com/products/jbatchupload). Costs $40 though.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are no jQuery or Flash or HTML plugins/tools you can use for this- at least that I am aware of because that would grant a lot of access to your OS.

You will most likely need make an applet or Active X control.

As already mentioned, Aurigma is a working example.

Hope that helps.